# How to allow HTTP traffic in app.json for IOS and Android before pushing the app to store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, configure

Im trying to configure the app.json before publishing the app to store, but I cant find any info how to allow HTTP traffic for Android and Ios. Can someone help me please??

Answer (score 1):

For IOS add below code in your info.plist :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

For Android add the below code in your application tag of the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: I dont have the info.plist, is there any other way?

Comment: please check the ios directory of your project => PROJECT_DIR => info.plist